# Pressing back in a nested view throws the error "The specified child already has a parent."

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have nested views set up with `BottomNavigation` whereby users may navigate to one of the details "page" from a `ListView`. I have tried Manual Routing as well as Vue Navigator

Here is the layout of my app.

```
<!--Main.vue-->
  <Page>
    <BottomNavigation>
      <TabStrip class="bottom-navigation">
        ...
      </TabStrip>

      <TabContentItem>
        <Frame>
          <Dashboard />
        </Frame>
      </TabContentItem>

      <TabContentItem>
        <Frame>
          <Finance />
        </Frame>
      </TabContentItem>

      <TabContentItem>
        <Frame>
          <Profile />
        </Frame>
      </TabContentItem>
    </BottomNavigation>
  </Page>

<!--Finance.vue-->
  <Page>
    <Tabs>
      <TabStrip class="tab-strip">
        ...
      </TabStrip>

      <TabContentItem>
        <ListView
          for="item in items"
          @itemTap="$navigateTo(detailPage)"
          class="list-group"
          height="100%"
        >
          ...
        </ListView>
      </TabContentItem>

      <TabContentItem>
        ...
      </TabContentItem>
    </Tabs>
  </Page>


<!--ItemDetails.vue-->
  <Page>
    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
        <NavigationButton @tap="$navigateBack" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"/>
        <Label class="action-bar-title" :text="item.name"></Label>
    </ActionBar>

    <GridLayout>
        ...
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
```

Here's the error that appears on pressing the back button of the details page.

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5042)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4873)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4813)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4786)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

App crashes and I am unable to figure out what could be causing the error. Please help.

Comment: Please share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the core modules to the latest version, it was fixed in 6.1or 6.2